# Composer [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package mtibben/html2text

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have tried to install `html2text` via composer to my laravel application. Here is a link to the `html2text` repository. https://github.com/mtibben/html2text

I have tried `composer require mtibben/html2text` giving this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Could not find package mtibben/html2text at any version for your
>   minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spel   ling or your
>   minimum-stability

Also I have tried `composer require https://github.com/mtibben/html2text.git` giving this error:

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>   Could not parse version constraint //github.com/mtibben/html2text.git:
>   Invalid version string "//github.com/mtibben   /html2text.git"

[image]

How do I install html2text?

Comment: try this https://github.com/soundasleep/html2text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a php package, u can't install with composer require

U may want to read this tutorial

http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-use-external-classes-and-php-files-in-laravel-controller/

Comment: Worked a treat, just threw the class into App\Helpers and it works a treat. Thanks Arun.

Answer (score 1):

Do you already have a **composer.json** file in your directory? If not, this could be the error, because in this file you will configure which version of the package you want to install in to your project.

The second exception gives a hint to that missing version!

If you have a composer.json file please add its content to your question, so that we can take a look at it.

**Here you can find further informations:**

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-json-project-setup

Answer (score 1):

i faced the same problem.
And neither the creation of releases, nor any tags helped.

The solution for me turned out to be updating the composer from last version.

Answer (score 0):

it's for composer, nothing else. If you already installed composer and composer version is 2 then convert it to version 1.easy way to solve this problem is ,delete the composer folder from your system and re install it. download from here: https://getcomposer.org/